# Question on an induction

Tags: induction

Show that for every $n\ge2$,we have:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}<1-\frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}

Prove by induction:

1. Base case:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2^2}<\frac{1}{2},
\end{equation}
is valid.

2. We then assume that the statement is also true for $n=k$
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(k)^2}<1-\frac{1}{k}
   \end{equation}
3. We prove it for $n=k+1$
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}<1-\frac{1}{k+1}
   \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}<\frac{k}{k+1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots<\frac{k(k+1)-1}{(k+1)^2}
\end{equation}

Put $(k+1)=n$ and obtain:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots<\frac{(n-1)(n)-1}{(n)^2}
\end{equation}

But I can't solve this one.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You should rather assume that the statement is true for $n=k$ and prove it for $n=k+1$.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate

Comment: Where is the the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an induction don't write the result you want to arrive to and try to get it backward like you did.

Instead start with: let assume it is true for $n=k$ that $S_k<1-\frac 1k$

Then $S_{k+1}=S_k+\frac 1{(k+1)^2}<1-\frac 1k+\frac 1{(k+1)^2}<\cdots<1-\frac 1{k+1}$

so the induction is verified for $n=k+1$ and therefore for all $n$

(cf linked answer by D.W.Farlow for the final detailed calculation)

Comment: Do not answer duplicates !